# I need clarification on how to finish or configure installing sslstrip

Tags: ssl, kali-linux

I'm new to using Kali Linux, but I've been installing some programs to get started. I am tring to install Airgeddon, but it needs sslstrip.

It seems that I completed the installation, but it possibly needs to be configured as I can cd into sslstrip and python sslstrip.py -h into it. But on Airgeddon it says it still isn't installed.

Is this a configuration thing? Is it possibly the location? I'm not actually sure what got it to install, but I think the only thing left is possibly the last 3 steps on the "Running" section in the instructions here: https://github.com/moxie0/sslstrip
That's question 2-4 like setting up iptables.

Hope this is enough info, there are so many installation instructions online for this and it's confusing for a newby like me.

Edit: here is a screenshot of running sslstrip: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVUvk.png

Comment: You have not installed it but you have only unpacked it into some directory only known to you. Why don't you just use the normal way to install software on your system - see [How To Install sslstrip on kali](https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/s/sslstrip/install/index.html).

Comment: That's what I tried first, but I always get this;      https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXwZG.png

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with pip: `pip install sslstrip`

This will automatically add triggers for the package. Presently, you are running it manually from a git clone.

Alternatively you can install from the git clone with: `cd /root/sslstrip && python setup.py install`